# WebVTT captions not showing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, caption, subtitle, webvtt

I'm experimenting with WebVTT (.vtt) captions.

On Firefox, the caption works perfectly. On Chrome, it is not even shown.

I'm doing this on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xabaqo/edit?html,output).

Some codes, just in case:

```
<video height="300" controls>
<source src="http://www.royray.name/videos/FG-S07E03-Missile-Pact.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<track src="http://www.royray.name/videos/FG-S07E03-Missile-Pact.vtt" kind="captions" label="Closed Captions" default>
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but I had the same problem and it was that subtitles where being placed behind the video. So, adding:

```
video::-webkit-media-text-track-display {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-3em);
    transform: translateY(-3em);
}
```

solved my problem